# What are the "No Connect" terminals on this multiplexer and what purpose do they serve?

Tags: pcb, datasheet, multiplexer

I was looking through the [datasheet for the ADG506A/ADG507A](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADG506A_507A.pdf) and on the chip there are these terminal marked as NC and underneath the image it says "NC = NO CONNECT". They are also not explained in the terminology section of the datasheet and I am not sure whether I should have them connected to ground when I am using the chip or just leave them alone. What purpose do the serve anyways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No connect means just that -- don't connect the terminal to anything.  They often appear on devices because the manufacturer uses a standard form factor that has more terminals than are needed for that particular device.

Answer (score 5):

This is to confirm what @David wrote.  (+1 to him, by the way.)

> A terminal that has no internal connection and that can be used as a support for external wiring without disturbing the function of the device, provided that the voltage applied to this terminal (by means of the wiring) does not exceed the highest supply voltage rating of the circuit.  [JEDEC](https://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/dictionary/terms/no-internal-connection-pin-nc)

The datasheet for ADG706 doesn't mention what to do with the NC pins.  But more often than not, the datasheet mentions NC pins ([example, see p.5](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADXL335.pdf)).  I have once seen NC pins that were used for calibration by the manufacturer at the factory (can't recall which IC it was).  That NC pin had to be left unconnected, it had to be left floating.  That was an exception to the rule, and it was spelled out in the datasheet.

Comment: So they are either a support or a built in probe.

Comment: Is there an official JEDEC term for a pin that you must not connect to?